# Z3 tactic for finding partial assignment

Tags: z3

Suppose that I have a formula F which contains variables w, x, y, z.

Is there any tactic of Z3 that finds a partial model of F, but the partial model must contains assignments for y and z. (I don't care w and x.)

By applying this tactic, Z3 spends less time for finding the partial model than finding a full model.

Is there such tactic exists?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in tactic for doing that.
It is not cheap to find the precise set of "don't cares". 
Moreover, if `w` and `x` are really "don't cares", then they should not affect Z3's performance in a significant way.